# How can I find a Stable Diffusion program?

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request, artificial-intelligence, computation-models, image-processing

Well, I know that I'm going to ask too much.

So, I really want to ask you a totally (powerful (!)) free completely off-line code to generate **prompt-based** images like midjourney. I want to run with my graphics card and memory without any restrictions of time or number of images and completely private.

**My question is: do you know where to find these codes?**

*(!) that is in the same level of midjourney, night café and NOP's Colab stable*

Comment: I'm not sure that requests for software are on-topic here.  Asking how to do something is on-topic but I'm not sure about requests for recommendations of software.  If it is on-topic, it'll be important to explain how this is a question about computer science that is best answered by computer scientists.  I'm not sure what is meant by "prompt-based images" or "midjourney".

Answer (score 1):

These instructions aren't too bad:
https://www.howtogeek.com/830179/how-to-run-stable-diffusion-on-your-pc-to-generate-ai-images/

...but you'll do better by googling for install instructions specific to your OS. Stable Diffusion has different installer packages for Windows, OSX, and Linux, and getting instructions specific to the platform you're using will make things a bit easier.